# Importing geopandas keeps failing for Mac - All reported solutions tried

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, geopandas, fiona

Import geopandas gave me:
ImportError: No module named 'geopandas'
I researched and applied solutions:

!pip uninstall geopandas six pyproj fiona rtree shapely -y
!conda install -c conda-forge fiona shapely rtree pyproj geopandas six
!conda upgrade --all

The upgrade operation produced a bodacious list of files being updated and superseded. It concluded with the following message 8 times over, each with a different path:

CondaVerificationError: The package for gxx_impl_linux-64 located at /opt/conda/pkgs/gxx_impl_linux-64-7.2.0-hdf63c60_3
appears to be corrupted. The path 'bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-g++'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

When I then did the Import geopandas as gpd, I got the 'no module named geopandas' error message again.

I'm on a MacBook Pro using a Jupyter Notebook and I'm out of ideas. Anybody have another idea?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to create new conda environment with all necessary libraries. Before you do that check what channels you have in your conda settings.

```
$ conda config --get channels
--add channels 'defaults'   # lowest priority
--add channels 'conda-forge'   # highest priority
```

If you don't have anaconda and conda-forge you have to add them.

```
$ conda config --add channel conda-forge
```

Once it's done, create new environment. You don't need to pass `six`, `fiona` and other libraries because they will be installed along with `geopandas`. If you are using Jupyter I recommend you to install `ipykernel` which allow you to add your environment to list of Jupyter kernels.

```
conda create --name <name-of-your-env> python=3 geopandas=0.4.0 gdal ipykernel
```

Hit enter and wait for conda. When installation is finished, activate your environment, test it and if everything is fine register kernel.

```
conda activate <name-of-your-env>
python -m ipykernel --install --user --name <name-of-your-env> --display-name <name-to-be-displayed>
```

Enjoy your environment.

Comment: This is great.  This is all a big new adventure for me and you are opening up a new little frontier.  I really want to understand this stuff because it's key to accessing the enormous quantity of data available on national and state sites.  A few questions:

Comment: for <name-of-you-env>, are <> necessary or your notation? Do I find the name someplace or just make something up? For future projects, can I just repeat the last two instructions, or do I do the whole process again? In the config command, you had --add subcommands. Is the next command necessary? I don't see anaconda explicitly being added. Is that part of adding conda-forge?

Comment: <> are just placeholders for your env name (simply type test or something else). You can just use following lines for future reference
```
conda create --name new_env python=3 geopandas=0.4.0 gdal ipykernel
conda activate new_env
python -m ipykernel --install --user --name new_env --display-name new_env
```
You don't need to repeat anything before that commands.

Comment: I'm a little flummoxed.  The 'conda activate' seems to be 'conda source activate', I did that.  The problem I have is that in the ipykernal install, there is the --user.  I have nothing to put in, and it wants something, so I tried to create a user.  That gets me to anaconda-server-create-user --username jsmith --password
abc123DEF --email jsmith@acme.com from the manual. When I try to execute with my info, I'm informed that anaconda-server-create isn't a valid command. Bopping around anaconda and stack overflow hasn't made me smarter.

Comment: I may be creating confusion.  I'm doing this for Coursera course that is using Jupyter Notebook in IBM Watson Studio.  I don't know how to find what my anaconda server is.  I'm guessing that If I knew, I'd execute <server> create -user Ladeda --password abra12cedabra email dkdkd@ss.com.  Correct? Then I could use Ladeda in --user in command you provided, and all would work? Yes? Thanks

Comment: It just occurred to me: I'm loading folium and seaborn OK, so should all this other stuff you outlined be unnecessasry?  Maybe something else is amiss in loading geopandas?

Comment: @kil3r answer is referring to command line code, not python. I have no familiarity with IBM Watson or Jupyter, but I imagine that its causing issues here. Install anaconda on your local drive and then follow the answer above.